# Kurento : Custom module change version number

Tags: kurento

I have been trying to change the version number of kurento custom module, I was successful to change the version of the `jar` snapshot but not of the `.deb` file which is generated.
Can anyone point out how to change the version number of the output `.deb` file
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a new entry con debian/changelog the version on that entry will be the version of the package.

To make easier the creation of the entry you can use the command `dch`:

```
dch -i
```

This will open an editor with some of the field already completed. Just complete the missing ones with the correct information.

Comment: I tired `dch -i` it outputs this line `+3: No such file or directory`

Comment: I suppose that you have dch program installed. You have to run this command from project root (the one that contains the `debian` folder, not from the `debian` folder itself)

Comment: yes, I am running it from project root, i tried `dch -i "changes"` and then manually changed the version number in changelog. now its working